# Moving table by fixing vba code

Tags: vba, excel

I have an existing VBA code as following:

```
Sub fillDL()
    Dim cn As Object, lr As Integer, soct As Integer, i As Integer
    lr = Range("P31").End(xlDown).Row
    If lr > 32 Then Rows("32:" & lr - 1).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("AO1").Formula = "=COUNTA(AN:AN)"
    soct = Range("AO1").Value + 31
    If soct > 31 Then
        Rows("32:" & soct).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        cn.Open ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1"";")
        Range("A32").CopyFromRecordset cn.Execute("select b.f4, b.f5, b.f6, b.f7, '','','','','','','', '','','','','','', b.f9, b.f10,'','','','', b.f12,'','','','', b.f13,'','','','',b.f14 " & _
                                                    "from [BILL$AN1:AN] a inner join [pivot$A6:N] b on a.f1 = b.f1 where a.f1 is not null")"
```

Since it was written to run from row 31 onwards, but now I need to move the table from row 31 to row 11. Can u guys please help me to fix this VBA

Comment: Just change all occurrences of "31" to "11" and the one reference to "32" to "12"

Comment: cannot change like that, numbers in column AN won't be appeared until cell 12 to cell 32

Answer (score 0):

In the future, to allow yourself more flexibility with your code, you should add a `Const RowNum    As Long = 11` , and inside the `Sub` use the reference to `RowNum`. This way, if in the future you want to modify to row 150 (or whatever) you can modify it in a single place.

**Code**:

```
Option Explicit

Const RowNum    As Long = 11

Sub fillDL()

    Dim cn As Object, lr As Long, soct As Long, i As Long

    lr = Range("P" & RowNum).End(xlDown).Row

    If lr > RowNum + 1 Then Rows(RowNum + 1 & ":" & lr - 1).Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Range("AO1").Formula = "=COUNTA(AN:AN)"
    soct = Range("AO1").Value + RowNum
    If soct > RowNum Then
        Rows(RowNum + 1 & ":" & soct).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        ' rest of your code...
```